# Find HID/PID in DELPHI / ARDUINO Interface

Tags: arduino-uno

(First, I am not sure whether this question is placed in the correct section of Stack Exchange. If not so, please give me a notice and delete the question.)

I have 8 Arduino's (Ards). Some Uno's and some 2650 Mega's. In an attempt to automatize the connection process (I use Delphi D-7 SE as I/O), I want to differentate between the UNO and the 2650 (mostly because the hardware differences in the appropriate chip). The way to do this (I think), is to get the PID and VID from the board. But I don't know how to do this. The code below gives me the correct driver, but not PID/VID . Is it possible to get PID/VID for this code-snippet ??  IF so, HOW ?

Thanks a lot.

Code here:

```
unit ArduinoTestU;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics,
  Controls, Forms, Dialogs, JVsetupAPI, Registry, StdCtrls,
  CPortCtl, CPort, Menus, XPMan;

type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
    ListBox1: TListBox;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    function  SetupEnumAvailableComPorts  :  TstringList;
    procedure ListBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    ArdType :  Integer;
  end;

var
  MainForm          : TMainForm;
  ComPortStringList : TStringList;
  MyComPort         : String;
  CurDir            : String;

implementation

uses Form1Unit, ArdFormU; (* , ArdFormU;  *)



{$R *.dfm}

procedure TMainForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   MainForm.FormActivate(NIL);
end;

procedure TMainForm.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
var
   index : integer;

begin
   ComPortStringList := SetupEnumAvailableComPorts;
   if (ComPortStringList <> nil) and (ComPortStringList.Count > 0) then
      for Index := 0 to ComPortStringList.Count - 1 do
         Listbox1.Items.Add(ComPortStringList[Index]);
   if Listbox1.Items.Count <> 0 then
      BEGIN
         Listbox1.Enabled := True;
         Button1.Enabled := False;
      END;
end;

procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
BEGIN
   Curdir := ExtractFileDir(Application.Exename);
end;

(*
The function below returns a list of available COM-ports
(not open by this or an other process), with friendly names. The list is formatted as follows:

COM1: = Communications Port (COM1)
COM5: = NI Serial Port (Com5)
COM6: = NI Serial Port (Com6)
COM7: = USB Serial Port (COM7)
COM8: = Bluetooth Communications Port (COM8)
COM9: = Bluetooth Communications Port (COM9)

This code originally posted at http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_4001.asp?SK=
errors have been fixed so it will work with Delphi 7 and SetupAPI from JVCL
*)


function TMainForm.SetupEnumAvailableComPorts  :  TstringList;
//
// Enumerates all serial communications ports that are available and ready to
// be used.
//
var
  RequiredSize:             Cardinal;
  GUIDSize:                 DWORD;
  Guid:                     TGUID;
  DevInfoHandle:            HDEVINFO;
  DeviceInfoData:           TSPDevInfoData;
  MemberIndex:              Cardinal;
  PropertyRegDataType:      DWord;
  RegProperty:              Cardinal;
  RegTyp:                   Cardinal;
  Key:                      Hkey;
  Info:                     TRegKeyInfo;
  S1,S2:                    string;
  hc:                       THandle;

begin
   Result := Nil;
//
//If we cannot access the setupapi.dll then we return a nil pointer.
//
   if not LoadsetupAPI then
      exit;
   try
//
// get 'Ports' class guid from name
//
      GUIDSize := 1;    // missing from original code - need to tell function that the Guid structure contains a single GUID

      if SetupDiClassGuidsFromName('Ports',@Guid,GUIDSize,RequiredSize) then
         begin
//
//get object handle of 'Ports' class to interate all devices
//
            DevInfoHandle := SetupDiGetClassDevs(@Guid,Nil,0,DIGCF_PRESENT);
            if Cardinal(DevInfoHandle) <> Invalid_Handle_Value then
               begin
                  try
                     MemberIndex := 0;
                     result := TStringList.Create;

//iterate device list

                     repeat
                         FillChar(DeviceInfoData,SizeOf(DeviceInfoData),0);
                         DeviceInfoData.cbSize := SizeOf(DeviceInfoData);

//get device info that corresponds to the next memberindex

                         if Not SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(DevInfoHandle,MemberIndex,DeviceInfoData) then
                            break;

//query friendly device name LIKE 'BlueTooth Communication Port (COM8)' etc

                         RegProperty := SPDRP_FriendlyName;  {SPDRP_Driver, SPDRP_SERVICE, SPDRP_ENUMERATOR_NAME,SPDRP_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_OBJECT_NAME,SPDRP_FRIENDLYNAME,}
                         SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(DevInfoHandle, DeviceInfoData,RegProperty, PropertyRegDataType,NIL,0,RequiredSize);
                         SetLength(S1,RequiredSize);
                   //      ShowMessage('TEST:  ' + S1);

                         if SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(DevInfoHandle,DeviceInfoData,RegProperty,PropertyRegDataType,@S1[1],RequiredSize,RequiredSize) then
                            begin
                               KEY := SetupDiOpenDevRegKey(DevInfoHandle,DeviceInfoData,DICS_FLAG_GLOBAL,0,DIREG_DEV,KEY_READ);
                               if key <> INValid_Handle_Value then
                                  begin
                                     FillChar(Info, SizeOf(Info), 0);

//query the real port name from the registry value 'PortName'

                                     if RegQueryInfoKey(Key, nil, nil, nil, @Info.NumSubKeys,@Info.MaxSubKeyLen, nil, @Info.NumValues, @Info.MaxValueLen,
                                                        @Info.MaxDataLen, nil, @Info.FileTime) = ERROR_SUCCESS then
                                        begin
                                           RequiredSize := Info.MaxValueLen + 1;
                                           SetLength(S2,RequiredSize);




                                           if RegQueryValueEx(KEY,'PortName',Nil,@Regtyp,@s2[1],@RequiredSize) = Error_Success then
                                              begin
                                                 If (Pos('COM',S2) = 1) then
                                                    begin
                                                       //Test if the device can be used

                                                       hc := CreateFile(pchar('\\.\' + S2 + #0), GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE,
                                                             0, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
                                                       if hc <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
                                                          begin
                                                             Result.Add(Strpas(PChar(S2)) + ' := ' + StrPas(PChar(S1)));
                                                             CloseHandle(hc);
                                                          end;
                                                    end;
                                              end;
                                        end;
                                     RegCloseKey(key);
                                  end;


                            end;
                         Inc(MemberIndex);
                     until False;

//If we did not found any free com. port we return a NIL pointer.

                     if Result.Count = 0 then
                        begin
                           Result.Free;
                           Result := NIL;
                        end
                  finally
                     SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(DevInfoHandle);
                  end;
               end;
         end;
   finally
      UnloadSetupApi;
   end;
end;

procedure TMainForm.ListBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   Ardtype := Listbox1.ItemIndex;
   MainForm.Hide;
   ArdForm.ShowModal;
   if Ardform.ModalResult <> mrOK  then
      ShowMessage('Der opstod en fejl ')
   ELSE
      BEGIN
         MainForm.Show;
      END;
end;

end.
```

Kris aka snestrup2016

Comment: You don't get them from the board - you get them from your operating system's USB stack. There are probably Delphi libraries that interface with whatever interface Windows provides for such a task.

Comment: Thanks,  I'll search for it.   Or I'll place my question in the Delphi - section. Again:  Thanks a lot.